# Display DateTime like Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

I need to Display the Time In my GridView taking Data from Database.
I have the Time in the Format

```
2012-03-07 11:51:45.000
```

How can I show the DateTime In the following way Like Gmail Does?

[image]

If it is Todays Date the Time Should be displayed. Or else The Date Should be Displayed in this Format.

Can you Help Me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function in code behind that will cast your `DateTime` to the required format, and then render it using `TemplateField`.

Code:

```
protected string GetCustomDateFormat(object dateTimeObj)
{
    DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)dateTimeObj;

    if (dateTime.Date == DateTime.Today)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //This Gives the Time in the Format (ex: 8:30 PM)

        //return dateTime.ToShortTimeString();
        // or you can specify format: dateTime.ToString("t")
    }
    else
    {
        return dateTime.ToShortDateString();
        // or you can specify format: dateTime.ToString("m")
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...
    <Columns>
        ...
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header text here">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <%# this.GetCustomDateFormat(Eval("DateTimeFieldName")) %>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @KrishnaThota, updated the post to show more context of how this markup should be applied.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DateTime Formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to do something like this

```
public string ShowEmailAsGmail(DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if (dt.Date == now.Date)
        return dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");

    return dt.ToString("MMM dd");
}
```

You could have this as a property of your custom object like:

```
public class EmailItem { 

    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }

    public string ShowEmailAsGmail { get {
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (this.SentDate.Date == now.Date)
            return this.SentDate.ToString("HH:mm");

        return this.SentDate.ToString("MMM dd");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I convert it into AM and PM ?

Comment: in the first example `dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");` will show: `11:23 AM`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("d"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("D"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("f"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("F"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("g"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("m"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("M"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("o"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("O"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("s"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("t"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("T"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("u"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("U"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("y"));
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("Y"));
```

output:-

d    09/10/2012 
D    Monday, September 10, 2012
f    Monday, September 10, 2012 12:11 PM
F    Monday, September 10, 2012 12:12:22 PM
g    2/10/2012 12:12 PM
G    2/10/2012 12:12:22 PM
m    September 10
M    September 10
o    2012-02-10T12:12:22.1020000-08:00
O    2012-02-10T12:12:22.1020000-08:00
s    2012-02-10T12:12:22
t    12:12 PM
T    12:12:22 PM
u    2012-02-10 12:12:22Z
U    Monday, September 10, 2012 8:12:22 PM
y    September, 2012
Y    September, 2012

Answer (score 1):

Checkout following

```
 // create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

    String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
    String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
    String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
    String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
    String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
    String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
    String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
    String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
    String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
    String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone

// date separator in german culture is "." (so "/" changes to ".")
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2008 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2008 16:05:07" - german (de-DE)


// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                         ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                        ShortDate
String.Format("{0:T}", dt);  // "4:05:07 PM"                      LongTime
String.Format("{0:D}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008"          LongDate
String.Format("{0:f}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05 PM"  LongDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:F}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05:07 PM" FullDateTime
String.Format("{0:g}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05 PM"                ShortDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:G}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM"             ShortDate+LongTime
String.Format("{0:m}", dt);  // "March 09"                        MonthDay
String.Format("{0:y}", dt);  // "March, 2008"                     YearMonth
String.Format("{0:r}", dt);  // "Sun, 09 Mar 2008 16:05:07 GMT"   RFC1123
String.Format("{0:s}", dt);  // "2008-03-09T16:05:07"             SortableDateTime
String.Format("{0:u}", dt);  // "2008-03-09 16:05:07Z"            UniversalSortableDateTime
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if(myDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use date time formatters - for a comprehensive list (including samples), you can refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx